# Can't stop and reformat /dev/md0

Tags: centos, raid, mdadm, formatting, mkfs

I want to reformat /dev/md0, which is a RAID0 array consisting of 4 disks (sd[bcde]).  However, when I tried to run the command mke2fs, I received the following error message:

```
/dev/md0 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

I also tried mdadm --stop to stop it, but it didn't work:

```
mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md0:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group?
```

FYI, /dev/md0 is not mounted, and the output of lsof/fuser is just empty.
Any thoughts?

[Update1]

The output of lsblk is showed below:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0  21.9T  0 raid0 
sdc      8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0  21.9T  0 raid0 
sdd      8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0  21.9T  0 raid0 
sde      8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk  
└─md0    9:0    0  21.9T  0 raid0
```

The output of dmsetup table is "No devices found", and pvs produces nothing.

[Update2]

The disks only belong to /dev/md0 and are not in other RAID.  /dev/md0 used to be mounted as a NFS shared directory.  But even after I stopped nfs, it does not solve the problem.

No output for pvdisplay and vgdisplay.

For "dmsetup info", it says "No devices found".

The output of "cat /proc/mdstat":

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md2 : active raid5 sdp[4] sdo[3] sdn[2] sdm[1] sdl[0]
      23441565696 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
      bitmap: 3/44 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid5 sdk[5] sdj[4] sdi[3] sdh[2] sdg[1] sdf[0]
      29301957120 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 2/44 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid0 sde[3] sdd[2] sdc[1] sdb[0]
      23441565696 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

Output of mount:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda5 on /tmp type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /var type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
/dev/md2 on /backup type ext4 (rw)
/dev/md1 on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

Comment: did you reboot into single user mode?

Comment: @chicks Nope.  I'm sshing into it as root.

Comment: Check your gvfs setup.   It's not claiming the device?

Double check whether nfsd is still running.  I know, I know; but check once more.